# Spork and aliased helper method in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, spork

I have problem with Spork (v 1.0.0rc1) and Devise in my Rails application. I have this error when I run spork:

```
undefined method 'user_signed_in?' for class ApplicationController
```

In ApplicationController I have following lines:

```
alias logged_in? user_signed_in?
helper_method :logged_in?
```

When I remove these two lines, Spork works fine. I use logged_in? for historical reasons in views and I would like to continue to do so.

I have looked around and I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: in my `spec_helper.rb` i have this two lines for devisewith them `require "rails/application"` and 
`Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)`, try run spork with them

Comment: I already have those lines in spec_helper.rb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to "~> 0.9.0.rc" until they resolve it.